# How to ignore one file when having multiple files with same names

Tags: git

My folder tree looks as follows:

- main_folder/

  - .gitignore
  - file1.py
  - secondary_folder/

    - file1.py

I'm trying to ignore only the file1.py that **outside** the secondary_folder.
Already tried both `./file1.py` and `main_folder/file1.py` and `!secondary_folder/file1.py` but in all cases it includes both files.

Comment: "_in all cases it includes both files_" - do you mean *ignores* both?

Comment: @underscore_d no..it doesn't ignore both files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore `/file1.py`. The leading slash means "the directory where the `.gitignore` resides".